# ¿Qué hace el operador "? :" en C++?

Tags: c++, operador

Me encontré en muchas ocasiones con el operador " **? :** " en C++, busqué, pero no encontré un respuesta al respecto, y no tengo muy claro su función, por ejemplo, este es un fragmento en el que está el operador:

```
int conversor(char caracter) {
    return ( isdigit(caracter) ? 0 :
            (islower(caracter) ? 1 :
            (isupper(caracter) ? 2 :
            (caracter == ' ') ? 3 : 4)));
}
```

¿Qué función cumple el operador?,¿Qué significa el numero seguido del signo "?" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El operador `? :`, es el operador ternario. Evalúa la expresión antes del interrogante (`?`) y si dicha expresión se puede interpretar como verdadera, el resultado será la expresión después del interrogante, en caso contrario el resultado será la expresión después de los dos puntos `:`.

Conceptualmente se comportaría así:

```
bool valor = es_martes()? dia() == 13 : false;
```

Si es martes trece, `valor` contendrá `true`, ya que evaluará la expresión `dia() == 13`.

Esto en cuanto a las características generales del operador ternario, que puede ser encontrado en decenas de lenguajes como [c](/questions/tagged/c), [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [java](/questions/tagged/java), [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c), [swift](/questions/tagged/swift), [scala](/questions/tagged/scala), [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby), [lua](/questions/tagged/lua) por mencionar algunos. Ahora voy a mencionar las características especiales que tiene el operador ternario en C++:

### Sólo se evalúa la rama condicional que se cumple.

La parte del operador ternario que no se cumple, no se evalúa. Así que este código:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    auto a = []() { std::cout << "A"; return 1; };
    auto b = []() { std::cout << "B"; return 2; };

    std::cout << (argc <= 1? a(): b());

    return 0;
}
```

Mostrará `A1` para programas sin parámetros porque sólo ejecuta `a()`, si ejecutase ambos mostraría `AB1`.

### Funciona como valor derecho e izquierdo.

El operador ternario puede usarse a la derecha de una asignación:

```
float a = PI;
float b = PHI;
float mayor = a > b? a : b;
```

O puede usarse a la izquierda de una asignación:

```
int pares = 0;
int impares = 0;
int valor = 42;
(valor % 2? impares : pares) += 1;
```

### Todos los operandos se transforman al mismo tipo.

El tipo de la expresión completa del operador ternario, será el tipo común de todos los tipos de la expresión, por lo tanto:

```
auto a = (argc <= 1? 1.f: 2.);
auto b = (argc <= 1? 3l: 4u);
```

El tipo de `a` será `double` (que es el tipo común entre `1.f` que es `float` y `2.` que es `double`) mientras que el tipo de `b` será `long` (que es el tipo común entre `3l` que es `long` y `4u` que es `unsigned int`).

Hay que tener en cuenta que si interviene una transformación, la expresión con el operador ternario no podrá usarse como valor izquierdo:

```
auto tres = 3l;
auto cuatro = 4u;
(argc <= 1? tres : cuatro) = 5; // Error, expresión no asignable.
```

### El operador ternario, no es sobrecargable.

Sólo existen cuatro operadores en C++ que no puedan ser sobrecargados:

- El operador de ámbito `::`.
- El operador de acceso a miembro `.`.
- El operador de acceso desde puntero a miembro `.*`.
- **El operador ternario `?:`**.

Answer (score 6):

**Operador Condicional / Operador Ternario**

**Ejemplo**

Evalúa su primer operando y, si el valor resultante no es igual a cero, evalúa su segundo operando. De lo contrario, evalúa su tercer operando, como se muestra en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
a = b ? c : d;
```

Es equivalente a:

```
if (b)
    a = c;
else 
    a = d;
```

Para mayor información te dejo la siguiente ruta:
[https://riptutorial.com/operador_ternario](https://riptutorial.com/es/c/example/2158/operador-condicional---operador-ternario)

Answer (score 1):

Evalua la condición brindada antes del ?:, en caso esta se cumpla se realiza la operación antes del ":" o en su defecto se realiza la operación que continue al ":".

```
a>17 ? cout << "Mayor de edad" << endl : cout << "Menor de edad" << endl;
```

Es equivalente a:

```
if (a > 17){
  cout << "Mayor de edad";
}else{
  cout << "Menor de edad";
}
```